# rounded corner images for only certain corners with calayer's cornerRadius

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to only round the top left corner of an image so it can't fit appropriately into a group styled tableviewcell.  I can get 4 corners rounded with the below code.  Does anyone know a simple way to get just one of the corners rounded?

```
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
```

thanks.

Comment: please post ur code to do this.it will really helpful to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only practical way to do that is to draw the content yourself with rounded corners. You can round arbitrary corners by using the `mask` property with another layer that has the corners you want rounded drawn by hand, but that's significantly slower. If you can possibly take over drawing yourself, you should do so.