# Navigation bar with rounded corners

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar

I want to create a navigationbar like the one on the image

[image]

I know hot to make the 4 borders rounded but I need only the top borders to be rounded....

Comment: navigation bar or the tableView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an image with rounded corners at the top and square corners at the bottom.

Alternatively, check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172152/rounded-corner-images-for-only-certain-corners-with-calayers-cornerradius).